# App store submission with staging assets

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Our app uses asset downloads from a production server to serve up content. With our new version 2.0 of the app, we are updating the format of the content. The old 1.0 client won't be able to work with the 2.0 assets.

Hence, when it's time to submit to the App Store, we can't push the 2.0 assets to the server yet because the 2.0 app won't yet be available. So the problem is that during Apple review they're going to be looking at the old 1.0 assets, which also don't quite work in the 2.0 app.

Is there a way we can submit our app for review and have Apple use staging content so they are correctly looking at 2.0 assets with the 2.0 app? I assume there must be something in place for this, I know we can't be the first team to run into this issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/559745).

Answer (score 2):

Have `v1.x` and `v2.x` assets on your server at different locations. If `2.x` assets break `1.x` code then you don't want to overwrite them, since you will have users that don't update to `2.x` immediately, then find the app broken, only to leave you a bad review or leave your app perminently.

Point the `2.x` code to the `2.x` assets and the `1.x` code to the `1.x` assets.